# Transact-SQL Return Two Columns Sorted Randomly Relative to Each Other

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to query two columns from a table so the values in the two columns are sorted Randomly compared to each other. It is not sufficient to return the rows in random order. Values that were in different columns in the same row initially need to end up in Randomly different rows. If there's no one-step way to do this, then I need to figure out some indirect way to get that effect. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: " Values that were in different columns in the same row initially need to end up in Randomly different rows." - could you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Your question is not clear, you need to provide some supporting data.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I have some data in two columns that seems to have some statistical correlations that might or might not be accidental. I want to compare this with an example where the relationships truly are random to see if the number of correlations goes down.

Comment: For example, suppose the first column stores  foods and the second stores currencies. In the first row there is 'fish' and 'dollars', the second stores 'beef' and 'pesos', the third stores 'eggs' and 'rupees'. The query might return 'fish' and 'rupees', then 'beef' and 'dollars', then 'eggs' and 'pesos'. The second column is randomly reordered compared to the first one.

Comment: Add your structure and some example data to your questoin

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Is it a requirement that values paired in one source row _never_ appear in the same result row? If so, the results aren't quite random.

Comment: Thanks, I have bookmarked that article now. And no, it is not a requirement that values paired in one source row can never appear in the same result row. Sorry this was not clear in my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One (cumbersome) way to do it is to use a cte with `row_number`, `cross apply` and `newid`.

The key point here is to use row_number over a random value for each column, and then use that row_number to join the columns together. <strike>Using cross apply is necessary so that the `newId()` function will be called for each row.</strike> As demonstrated in Paparazzi's answer, cross apply is not necessary in this case.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    c1 int,
    c2 int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,7), (8,8), (9,9), (10,10)
```

The cte:

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT  c1,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c1Order) as RNc1,
            c2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY c2Order) as RNc2
    FROM @T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT NEWID() as c1Order,
        NEWID() as c2Order
    ) randomSorter
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT t0.c1, t1.c2
FROM cte as t0
INNER JOIN cte as t1 ON t0.RNc1 = t1.RNc2 
ORDER BY t0.RNc1
```

Result sample:

```
c1      c2
1       8
10      6
2       9
9       3
6       1
3       7
5       5
4       2
8       4
7       10
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/LVFD65286)

Comment: That is slick +1

Comment: Thanks, Zohar, your example introduces me to several new techniques! I appreciate your help, I was really stumped. And in future I will include the code to create and populate a sample table.

Answer (score 1):

Just a spin on answer from Zohar
Give the check to Zohar

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (iden int identity,c1 int, c2 int);

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,3), (2,2), (2,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,7), (6,7), (8,8), (9,9), (10,10);

select * 
  from @t 
 order by iden;

with cte as 
( SELECT c1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RNc1,
         c2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) as RNc2
    FROM @T
)

select cte1.c1, cte2.c2  
  from cte cte1 
  join cte cte2 
    on cte1.RNc1 = cte2.RNc2
 order by cte1.RNc1;
```

Comment: Nice. for some reason I had to use cross apply, I couldn't get it to work properly without it, but I see now that's possible. I must have messed something up in my original attempt. (or taken a wrong turn at albuquerque...)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Nice but not a +1.   I will remember that.

Comment: @Paparazzi While it is nice that you got it to work without the cross apply, this answer is really just a spin, as you wrote yourself, but hey, upvotes are free so take one.